# Disable TinyMCE Drag and Drop

Tags: uploads, media, tinymce, wp-editor, drag-drop

I would very much like to disable the drag and drop upload feature for tinyMCE (both the default one and the `wp_editor()` one) because it interacts with my custom pop up menus - ([WP Trac](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/28338)). Right now I'm trying to just disable the one with the actual `WP_Editor()` function. For some reason it doesn't seem to actually disable any drag and drop functionality and was wondering if I was doing something wrong. My function call looks like this:

```
wp_editor($meta_content, 'additionalTab', array(
    'wpautop'           =>  true,
    'media_buttons'     =>  false,
    'textarea_name'     =>  '_additional_content',
    'textarea_rows'     =>  15,
    'teeny'             =>  true,
    'drag_drop_upload'  =>  false
));
```

**The Expected Output** is that it should completely disable drag and drop uploads directly to the tinyMCE.

**The Actual Output** is that it doesn't do anything, it still allows you to drag and drop upload into the tinymce. Is there something wrong with what I'm doing or is there something inherieitnly wrong with `wp_editor()`?

Comment: Does [this help](http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=5090)?

Comment: That's quite strange, and I'm unable to reproduce it. What version of WordPress are you using? Where are you calling `wp_editor`? I am unable to reproduce this: setting `drag_drop_upload` to `true` enables it for me, and setting it to `false` disables it.

Comment: I'm calling it in a metabox callback function. changing it from true to false or vise-versa does nothing for me - it always allows drag / drop upload. I'm running 3.9.1 and I find this happening on multiple installs.

Comment: It seems like if you add more than 1 `wp_editor` and one is true it makes them all true. I wonder if it's due to the static nature of the _WP_Editors::$drag_drop_upload variable? See https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-wp-editor.php#L27 I believe you said you weren't using wp_editor on both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can solve this problem by enqueue the following script with the dependency of jQuery

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      tinyMCEPreInit.dragDropUpload = false;
 });
```

To add the dependency you can refer [this link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Link_a_Theme_Script_Which_Depends_on_jQuery)

I have tested this solution and it has worked for me. I hope it will work for you too.